# "Crosstab" Query Only Showing Most Recent Results

Tags: mysql, pivot, crosstab

I have a query in MySQL set up to return the results with months as column headers and trainer names as the row headers.  I'm trying to determine the trainer's NPS score by month.  When I run the query, it only shows results for the last month in which they have survey results.  How can I fix the query to show results for every month they have survey scores?

Basic table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE nh_survey (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  trainer TINYINT(1),
  trainer_nps TINYINT(1),
  class_Date DATE
);
INSERT INTO nh_survey
  (trainer,trainer_nps,class_Date)
VALUES
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-21'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-21'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-21'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-21'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-25'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-21'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-21'''),
  ('''3''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-14'''),
  ('''3''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-14'''),
  ('''3''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-14'''),
  ('''3''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-14'''),
  ('''3''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-14'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''7''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''16''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''9''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-07'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-10-04'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-30'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''8''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''6''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-23'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-26'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-20'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''1992-10-07'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-16'''),
  ('''21''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-20'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-10'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''19''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-09'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-09-03'''),
  ('''16''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-26'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-26'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-26'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-26'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-26'''),
  ('''20''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-26'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-07-22'''),
  ('''16''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''8''',' ''2019-08-23'''),
  ('''16''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''15''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-19'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-05'''),
  ('''1''',' ''10''',' ''2019-08-05''');

CREATE TABLE trainers (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  revname VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO trainers
  (id,revname)
VALUES
  (1,'Trainer 1'),
  (2,'Trainer 2'),
  (3,'Trainer 3'),
  (4,'Trainer 4'),
  (6,'Trainer 5'),
  (7,'Trainer 6'),
  (8,'Trainer 7'),
  (9,'Trainer 8'),
  (10,'Trainer 9'),
  (11,'Trainer 10'),
  (12,'Trainer 11'),
  (13,'Trainer 12'),
  (15,'Trainer 13'),
  (16,'Trainer 14'),
  (18,'Trainer 15'),
  (19,'Trainer 16'),
  (20,'Trainer 17'),
  (21,'Trainer 18'),
  (22,'Trainer 19'),
  (23,'Trainer 20'),
  (24,'Trainer 21');
```

Here's the query:

```
select t1.revname AS 'Trainer',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =12, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Dec',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =1, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Jan',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =2, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Feb',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =3, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Mar',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =4, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Apr',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =5, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'May',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =6, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Jun',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =7, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Jul',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =8, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Aug',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =9, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Sep',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =10, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Oct',
 IF( MONTH( t2.class_date) =11, round(sum(t2.npscore)/count(t2.npscore)*100, 1 ),0)  AS 'Nov'
from
(select id, revname
from trainers
where id in(1,2,3,15,16,18,19,20,21)) t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    trainer, 
    class_date,     
        CASE
                WHEN trainer_nps IN (9 , 10) THEN 1
                WHEN trainer_nps IN (7 , 8) THEN 0
                ELSE - 1
            END AS npscore            
    FROM
        nh_survey
        Where class_date between '2018-01-28' and '2019-11-30') t2 on t1.id = t2.trainer
group by t1.revname
order by t1.id ASC
```

If I group by just the trainer, it only gives me the last month for which a trainer has survey results.  If I add class_date to the grouping, it gives me 12 rows for each trainer.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your post

Comment: Edited to include tables

Answer (score 0):

I had to adept your data a bit.
With this data

```
  CREATE TABLE nh_survey (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    trainer TINYINT(1),
    trainer_nps TINYINT(1),
    class_Date DATE
  );
  INSERT INTO nh_survey
    (trainer,trainer_nps,class_Date)
  VALUES
    ('1','10','2019-10-21'),
    ('1',' 10','2019-10-21'),
    ('1','10','2019-10-21'),
    ('1','10','2019-10-21'),
    ('1','10','2019-10-25'),
    ('1','10','2019-10-21'),
    ('1','10','2019-10-21'),
    ('3','10','2019-10-14'),
    ('3','10','2019-10-14'),
    ('3','10','2019-10-14'),
    ('3','10','2019-10-14'),
    ('3','10','2019-10-14'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','7','2019-10-07'),
    ('16','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','9','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('15','10','2019-10-07'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-10-04'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-30'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','8','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','6','2019-09-23'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-23'),
    ('15','10','2019-09-26'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-20'),
    ('21','10','1992-10-07'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-16'),
    ('21','10','2019-09-20'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-10'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('19','10','2019-09-09'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('20','10','2019-09-03'),
    ('16','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('20','10','2019-08-26'),
    ('20','10','2019-08-26'),
    ('20','10','2019-08-26'),
    ('20','10','2019-08-26'),
    ('20','10','2019-08-26'),
    ('20','10','2019-08-26'),
    ('15','10','2019-07-22'),
    ('16','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','8','2019-08-23'),
    ('16','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('15','10','2019-08-19'),
    ('1','10','2019-08-05'),
    ('1','10','2019-08-05');

  CREATE TABLE trainers (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    revname VARCHAR(255)
  );
  INSERT INTO trainers
    (id,revname)
  VALUES
    (1,'Trainer 1'),
    (2,'Trainer 2'),
    (3,'Trainer 3'),
    (4,'Trainer 4'),
    (6,'Trainer 5'),
    (7,'Trainer 6'),
    (8,'Trainer 7'),
    (9,'Trainer 8'),
    (10,'Trainer 9'),
    (11,'Trainer 10'),
    (12,'Trainer 11'),
    (13,'Trainer 12'),
    (15,'Trainer 13'),
    (16,'Trainer 14'),
    (18,'Trainer 15'),
    (19,'Trainer 16'),
    (20,'Trainer 17'),
    (21,'Trainer 18'),
    (22,'Trainer 19'),
    (23,'Trainer 20'),
    (24,'Trainer 21');
```

This select statement

```
  SELECT MAX(Trainer) Trainer
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =1, score, 0 ))  AS 'Jan'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =2, score,0 ))  AS 'Feb'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =3, score,0 ))  AS 'Mar'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =4, score, 0 ))  AS 'Apr'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =5, score,0 ))  AS 'May'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =6, score,0 ))  AS 'Jun'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =7, score, 0 ))  AS 'Jul'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =8, score,0 ))  AS 'Aug'
   ,SUM( IF( monthnb =9, score,0 ))  AS 'Sep'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =10, score, 0 ))  AS 'Oct'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =11, score,0 ))  AS 'Nov'
   ,SUM(IF( monthnb =12, score,0 ))  AS 'Dec'
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id,revname AS 'Trainer'
  ,MONTH(class_date)  monthnb
  ,round(sum(npscore)/count(npscore)*100) score
  FROM
  (select id, revname
  from trainers
  where id in(1,2,3,15,16,18,19,20,21)) t1
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT 
      trainer, 
      class_date,     
          CASE
                  WHEN trainer_nps IN (9 , 10) THEN 1
                  WHEN trainer_nps IN (7 , 8) THEN 0
                  ELSE - 1
              END AS npscore            
      FROM
          nh_survey
          Where class_date between '2018-01-28' and '2019-11-30') t2 on t1.id = t2.trainer    
   GROUP BY id,revname, MONTH(class_date) 
   ) tr1
GROUP BY id;
```

Will give following result

> ```
> Trainer      | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
> :----------- | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --: | --:
> Trainer 1    |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 |   0 | 100 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 3    |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 13   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 |  90 | 100 |  92 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 14   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 |   0 | 100 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 16   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 | 100 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 17   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 |  81 |   0 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 18   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 | 100 |   0 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 2    |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0
> Trainer 15   |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0
> ```

See dbfiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac5c062b818171cf47ddb16bec81ff99

Comment: Thank you nbk.  This is **exactly** what I needed.  I'll have to study it to understand what it's doing, but it gives me exactly what I wanted.  Thank you so much!  I upvoted your answer, but don't have enough points for it to display.